# MoveTo drawing a line?

Tags: javascript, drawing

```
<script>

function myFunction2() {


side1 = prompt("Enter the X axis of the bottom side")

side2 = prompt("Enter the X axis of the left side")

side3 = prompt("Enter the X axis of the right side")



var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 200);

context.lineTo(side1, 200);
context.stroke();
context.lineTo(side2, 100);
context.stroke();
context.lineTo(side3, 200);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

}

</script>
```

I'm trying to make a triangle so that a user can enter its sides lengths, but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.moveTo(0, 200);` moves your 'pen' (starting point) to 0, 200 which becomes the starting point for your first line. Your first line **ends** at `side1, 200`. This probably isn't what you want.

Rewrite your code like this:

```js
context.beginPath();

context.moveTo(side1, 200); // Start point for line 1
context.lineTo(side2, 100); // End point for line 1, start for line 2
context.stroke();
context.lineTo(side3, 200); // End point for line 2, start for line 3
context.stroke();
context.lineTo(side1, 200); // End point for line 3, back where we started
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```